# How to translate Decimal128 values over Rest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, restify

I'm using Mongoose as part of a package , saving heaps of time.

The package I am using is https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose. When I query Mongodb , and I have a Decimal128 type , it returns those values like this:

```
{
    "sku": "shGHYB12-60-LOZ",
    "name": "Prd",
    "size": "60",
    "buyPrice": {
        "$numberDecimal": "12.55"
    }
}
```

Which is fine when it's in a Mongoose object , but when I expose it over the Rest API ( this package uses restify ) , it is just a json representation.

If I post it back through the REST Api in a Patch or Put request - just as a string or number ( see below )  , it works fine and stores it in the database correctly translating it using the Mongoose model.

```
{
    "sku": "shGHYB12-60-LOZ",
    "name": "Prd",
    "size": "60",
    "buyPrice": "12.5995"
}
```

The Part of my mongoose model is like this

```
"buyPrice": {
    "type": "Decimal"
}
```

How can I store it as a decimal type in MongoDb but expose it as a number over REST? I'm just not sure how to go about it.

The 3 areas it could happen I guess are

1. The Mongoose model
2. Restify
3. Some sort of "hook" in Mongoose.

I'm not overly familiar with either. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could massage the data structure a little bit before you send it out (maybe in the controller or better yet by creating a model wrapper function). Use parseFloat("1.23") to turn the string representation into a float.

Comment: @HeadCode  the whole point of Decimal128 is to avoid the float type.

Comment: A float is a decimal. Your question might need some clarification.

Comment: @HeadCode I hope these will help you understand the difference. http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html  , https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/decimal128.html .  This is why I am referring to Decimal128 , which solves the rounding issues with the float type.  If you have something that will help me then please post an answer , otherwise please just let it rest! Thanks.

Comment: @MartinThompson were you able to figure it out? All the answers I got are converting back to Float and not Decimal128.

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper function before declaring a schema:

```
   function getMoney(value) {
      if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
         return parseFloat(value.toString());
      }
      return value;
    }
```

Add a getter to your field like this:

```
price: {
      type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
      get: getMoney
    },
```

Comment: I also though of the same idea, but this doesn't seem to work for me